# Unit testing : Why is it necessary

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Hello I will try to explain what is my actual understanding of unit test and why I have problems to grasp it's utility.

Even if I try my hardest to understand the concept of TTD, unit test, integration test, etc. From the most articles that I read it explain HOW to do it (with a trivial example or a framework) and sometimes how the tests saved them hours of debug in certain situation. And I have two problems with that :

**First : the method**

Let's use a basic example for the explaination of how to do a unit test :

> You want to test that your add function works as expected so in your test files you write a mock of your function with an expected output lets say something like that :
>
> ```
> import add from ./calculate
> function myTestingFunction() {
>     add(3, 5)
>     expectedOutput(8)
> }
> ```

Okay so you explain me how to do it but not why... and even with that, I have multiple questions :

- You're testing a function with another function ... so why did you stop there and test the function you just created ?
- It's code, it has algorithm so how to be sure it is correctly written
  ?
- And why stop with the expected output ? Why not testing that the
  input are of the correct type, because if I give charcarters to my
  add function it will fail, no ?

And every article is basically like that. So with that questions in mind I cannot find the motivation to even try this methods : it's just don't seems logic.

**Second : Tests are time and money saving**

Let's say now I want to test the *Divide* function the same way and write and expected output of 3 for the input 9 and 3.

Okay so I write the same function than explained before.
But if the user tries to divide by 0 a serious bug will logically occur for him ... this test doesn't covers this case and I'm writing test to ensure my code works well (or at least give the correct outputs).

In real life I now see two situation :

- I had explained to my client that I will take more time to code (so he will pay me more) but as a result he will be sure that in final his functions are bullet proof. And here I'm saying to him "Well ... sorry I didn't think about this use case" "So I pay you more because you said that the tests you've written will ensure a bug free app... but it's not ? And now I have to pay you to debug it ?" (so no time and money save and a bad relation with my client)
- I had coded the functionnality as explained and understood by me and my client. The new use case occur that we were'nt aware of. 'Kay no problem : I pull a branch to bug fix, fix the bug, push the hotfix, document the special use case if needed. And now in the future if I encounter an equivalent problematic I will have the algorithm already prepared because I faced the issue (time and money save for me and my client and a better relation overall)

I don't know if I'm clear about my state of mind but I've discussed these elements with many of my colleagues (some even with more years of practice or a better school degree than me) and they had the same problem than me about test : even if we really want to understand this topic and implement a good way of working if needed, as of now i'ts seems like some sort of intelectual pride.

Comment: This is off topic for this site but probably better suited for the computing stack exchange. I can’t remember the exact name of it. But as a quick comment… there is no possible way that you can hold an entire project of code in your head at one time. If you change your add function because it looks broken in one place, how do you know if it has broken any other place? If you want to restrictive your project, how do you know if the new structure works. You test to make it more convenient to be flexible with the project and to know that things are not broken accidentally (by another dev maybe)

Comment: https://www.codemag.com/Article/1901071/10-Reasons-Why-Unit-Testing-Matters There are other reasons given here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on this site… https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Automate testing. Secure the source. Speeds up the development process. But you're asking this in the wrong forum.

Comment: If you want to know how unit testing and other agile practices work together to form the modern software development methodology, study XP (eXtreme Programming). I don't recommend studying Scrum, because it has an overwhelming focus on the planning aspect, and its practitioners have a tendency to forget pretty much everything else, and then you no longer have an effective methodology.

Comment: Basically that's how testing works. You have to cover all the edge cases in unit testing. You cannot determine by any algorithm whether the test case you've written is correct or not. You should check that with client.There is no such thing as a bug free application practically. So don't sweat on it. Test rigorously. That's the only way to maintain good rapport with the client. Automation can be much helpful for larger projects to ensure that change in already existing code doesn't affect the other existing logic. If the logic changes you've to update test case eventually. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Fogmeister I'll try to look at the right forum to ask my question (if it's not already there) 

I didn't know about eXtreme Programming so I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

from my personal experience the answer boils down to one word -> CONFIDENCE.

After a period of time or when the codebase gets bigger and you are no longer familiar with the code anymore, it become problematic to easily change the code if there are not adequate unit tests in place to ensure the expected functionality.  If there is good unit test coverage in the area of change, then I am more confident that any changes I make will not introduce any unintended side-effects (READ: bugs here).

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I understand well the utility will not occur to me with the example I gave (and the one I found in articles) and testing find it's purpose in long term project that tends to be bigger with time. 

Maybe thats why I have problem to start it, because I only see it's basic implementation.

Comment: You're very welcome.  I think it is right that you question things and want to value them rather than blindly follow along.  KUDOS!